# Is there a difference between arguments and parameters?

Tags: terminology, functions, methods

It might be like this: Parameter means from the callers POV and arguments mean inside the procedure, or other way round.

Or is there no difference?

### Update

In Swedish we say "anropsparametrar" i.e. "parameters that are calling the procedure" and we would not say "anropsargument" ("arguments that are calling the procedure").

Comment: it will depend on context, that you refer

Comment: Please search next time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176310/difference-between-parameter-and-argument

Comment: @Overv Even that one is a duplicate. This question has been asked a billion times. Can't believe a bounty was set.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kewt1b3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)  there are some definition differences what is called parameter and what is called argument:

**Parameter:**

> A parameter represents a value that the procedure expects you to pass when you call it. The procedure's declaration defines its parameters.

**Argument:**

> An argument represents the value you pass to a procedure parameter when you call the procedure. The calling code supplies the arguments when it calls the procedure.

There is also a **great quote how to understand it in real-life** example:

> To communicate this information to the procedure, the procedure defines a parameter, and the calling code passes an argument to that parameter. You can think of the parameter as a parking place and the argument as an automobile. Just as different automobiles can park in the parking place at different times, the calling code can pass a different argument to the same parameter each time it calls the procedure.

Comment: The C# language specification agrees with this. For example,  section "1.6.6.1 Parameters" states that "The parameters of a method get their actual values from the arguments that are specified when the method is invoked."